# Access ChromeOs local web server from mobile

Tags: networking, localhost, chromebook, google-chrome-os

From a ChromeOs a access the linux localhost from `penguin.linux.test:<port>`, what is the equivalent of the address `100.115.92.200:<port>`. And I don't know how to access it from my  browser.

I've tried:

- to connect from my mobile browser to this address `100.115.92.200:<port>`.
- to create an ssh tunnel to forward the container port.
- to access a real localhost created with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related), but it also didn't work.